# Cannot make table responsive

Tags: html, css, bootstrap-4

I have a table with really large content and I'm trying to make it responsive using Bootstrap:

```html
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.0.1/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.0.1/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<html>
  <head></head>
  <body>
    <table class="table">
      <tbody>
        <tr>
          <td>
            <p style="text-align: center">
              <strong>TELEPHONE CALL CENTER</strong>
            </p>
            <p style="text-align: center">&nbsp;</p>
            <p style="text-align: center"><strong>Timetables:</strong></p>
            <p style="text-align: center">
              Monday and Friday: <strong>9.00 - 12.00</strong>
            </p>
            <p style="text-align: center">
              Tuesday and Thursday: <strong>15.00 – 17.00</strong>
            </p>
            <p style="text-align: center"><strong>&nbsp;</strong></p>
            <p style="text-align: center">
              It is possible to access the call-center services, at the
              scheduled times, by calling the following numbers:
            </p>
            <p style="text-align: center"><strong>&nbsp;</strong></p>
            <p style="text-align: center"><strong>0000-00000</strong></p>
            <p style="text-align: center"><strong>000-00000</strong></p>
            <p style="text-align: center"><strong>000-00000</strong></p>
            <p style="text-align: center">&nbsp;</p>
          </td>
          <td>
            <p style="text-align: center"><strong>WHATSAPP DOORS</strong></p>
            <p style="text-align: center">&nbsp;</p>
            <p style="text-align: center"><strong>Timetables:</strong></p>
            <p style="text-align: center">
              Monday and Friday: <strong>9.00 - 12.00</strong>
            </p>
            <p style="text-align: center">
              Tuesday and Thursday: <strong>15.00 – 17.00</strong>
            </p>
            <p style="text-align: center"><strong>&nbsp;</strong></p>
            <p style="text-align: center">
              It is possible to access the Whatsapp counters, at the scheduled
              times, by sending a message to the following telephone numbers:
            </p>
            <p style="text-align: center"><strong>&nbsp;</strong></p>
            <p style="text-align: center"><strong>000-000000</strong></p>
            <p style="text-align: center"><strong>000-0000000</strong></p>
          </td>
          <td>
            <p style="text-align: center">
              <strong>SKYPE AUDIO-VIDEO DOORS</strong>
            </p>
            <p style="text-align: center">&nbsp;</p>
            <p style="text-align: center"><strong>Orari:</strong></p>
            <p style="text-align: center">
              Monday and Friday: <strong>9.00 - 12.00</strong>
            </p>
            <p style="text-align: center">
              Tuesday and Thursday: <strong>15.00 – 17.00</strong>
            </p>
            <p style="text-align: center"><strong>&nbsp;</strong></p>
            <p style="text-align: center">
              It is possible to access the Skype counters, at the scheduled
              times, by contacting the following addresses:
            </p>
            <p style="text-align: center"><strong>&nbsp;</strong></p>
            <p style="text-align: center"><strong>ID: foo</strong></p>
            <p style="text-align: center"><strong>ID: foo2</strong></p>
            <p style="text-align: center"><strong>ID: foo3</strong></p>
            <p>&nbsp;</p>
          </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>
            <p>&nbsp;</p>
            <figure class="image image_resized" style="width: 60.07%">
              <img src="https://i.imgur.com/II14v2c.png" />
            </figure>
          </td>
          <td>
            <figure class="image image_resized" style="width: 72.03%">
              <img src="https://i.imgur.com/IAZF2Rz.png" />
            </figure>
          </td>
          <td>
            <figure class="image image_resized" style="width: 75.72%">
              <img src="https://i.imgur.com/iJ2kk8j.png" />
            </figure>
          </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td colspan="3">
            <p style="text-align: center"><strong>Mail List:</strong></p>
          </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>
            <p style="text-align: center"><strong>123</strong></p>
            <p style="text-align: center"><i>foo@gmail.com</i></p>
          </td>
          <td>
            <p style="text-align: center"><strong>456</strong></p>
            <p style="text-align: center"><i>foo2@gmail.com</i></p>
          </td>
          <td>
            <p style="text-align: center"><strong>789</strong></p>
            <p style="text-align: center"><i>foo3@gmail.com</i></p>
          </td>
        </tr>
      </tbody>
    </table>
  </body>
</html>
```

The table looks pretty much well on desktop, but on mobile resolution it have some issues.

The mobile visualization is actually messed up, could please someone tell me how to optimize the table above in order to display correctly both in desktop and mobile?

Many thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem lies with your image being too huge, I have replaced it with the responsive image class from bootstrap. You can find more relevant details [here](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/5.0/content/images/).

```html
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.0.1/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.0.1/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<html>
  <head></head>
  <body>
    <table class="table">
      <tbody>
        <tr>
          <td>
            <p style="text-align: center">
              <strong>TELEPHONE CALL CENTER</strong>
            </p>
            <p style="text-align: center">&nbsp;</p>
            <p style="text-align: center"><strong>Timetables:</strong></p>
            <p style="text-align: center">
              Monday and Friday: <strong>9.00 - 12.00</strong>
            </p>
            <p style="text-align: center">
              Tuesday and Thursday: <strong>15.00 – 17.00</strong>
            </p>
            <p style="text-align: center"><strong>&nbsp;</strong></p>
            <p style="text-align: center">
              It is possible to access the call-center services, at the
              scheduled times, by calling the following numbers:
            </p>
            <p style="text-align: center"><strong>&nbsp;</strong></p>
            <p style="text-align: center"><strong>0000-00000</strong></p>
            <p style="text-align: center"><strong>000-00000</strong></p>
            <p style="text-align: center"><strong>000-00000</strong></p>
            <p style="text-align: center">&nbsp;</p>
          </td>
          <td>
            <p style="text-align: center"><strong>WHATSAPP DOORS</strong></p>
            <p style="text-align: center">&nbsp;</p>
            <p style="text-align: center"><strong>Timetables:</strong></p>
            <p style="text-align: center">
              Monday and Friday: <strong>9.00 - 12.00</strong>
            </p>
            <p style="text-align: center">
              Tuesday and Thursday: <strong>15.00 – 17.00</strong>
            </p>
            <p style="text-align: center"><strong>&nbsp;</strong></p>
            <p style="text-align: center">
              It is possible to access the Whatsapp counters, at the scheduled
              times, by sending a message to the following telephone numbers:
            </p>
            <p style="text-align: center"><strong>&nbsp;</strong></p>
            <p style="text-align: center"><strong>000-000000</strong></p>
            <p style="text-align: center"><strong>000-0000000</strong></p>
          </td>
          <td>
            <p style="text-align: center">
              <strong>SKYPE AUDIO-VIDEO DOORS</strong>
            </p>
            <p style="text-align: center">&nbsp;</p>
            <p style="text-align: center"><strong>Orari:</strong></p>
            <p style="text-align: center">
              Monday and Friday: <strong>9.00 - 12.00</strong>
            </p>
            <p style="text-align: center">
              Tuesday and Thursday: <strong>15.00 – 17.00</strong>
            </p>
            <p style="text-align: center"><strong>&nbsp;</strong></p>
            <p style="text-align: center">
              It is possible to access the Skype counters, at the scheduled
              times, by contacting the following addresses:
            </p>
            <p style="text-align: center"><strong>&nbsp;</strong></p>
            <p style="text-align: center"><strong>ID: foo</strong></p>
            <p style="text-align: center"><strong>ID: foo2</strong></p>
            <p style="text-align: center"><strong>ID: foo3</strong></p>
            <p>&nbsp;</p>
          </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>
            <p>&nbsp;</p>
            <img src="https://i.imgur.com/II14v2c.png" class="img-fluid"/>
          </td>
          <td>
            <img src="https://i.imgur.com/IAZF2Rz.png" class="img-fluid"/>
          </td>
          <td>
            <img src="https://i.imgur.com/iJ2kk8j.png" class="img-fluid"/>
          </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td colspan="3">
            <p style="text-align: center"><strong>Mail List:</strong></p>
          </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>
            <p style="text-align: center"><strong>123</strong></p>
            <p style="text-align: center"><i>foo@gmail.com</i></p>
          </td>
          <td>
            <p style="text-align: center"><strong>456</strong></p>
            <p style="text-align: center"><i>foo2@gmail.com</i></p>
          </td>
          <td>
            <p style="text-align: center"><strong>789</strong></p>
            <p style="text-align: center"><i>foo3@gmail.com</i></p>
          </td>
        </tr>
      </tbody>
    </table>
  </body>
</html>
```